# Nearest-neighbor data structure for non-Euclidean configuration space

Tags: motion-planning, rrt

I'm trying to implement a nearest-neighbor structure for use in an RRT motion planner. In order to do better than a linear brute-force nearest-neighbor search, I'd like to implement something like a kd-tree. However, it seems like the classical implementation of the kd-tree assumes that each dimension of the space can be split into "left" and "right". This notion doesn't seem to apply to non-Euclidean spaces like SO(2), for instance.

I'm working with a serial manipulator arm with fully rotational links, meaning that each dimension of the robot's configuration space is SO(2), and therefore non-Euclidean. Can the kd-tree algorithm be modified to handle these kinds of subspaces? If not, is there another nearest-neighbor structure that can handle these non-Euclidean subspaces while still being easy to update and query? I also took a look at [FLANN](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~mariusm/index.php/FLANN/FLANN), but it wasn't clear to me from their documentation whether they can handle non-Euclidean subspaces.

Comment: By the way, approximate nearest-neighbors is fine too (even preferred, if the speedup is considerable)

Comment: While you have accepted an excellent answer, it is usually a good idea to wait a few days before accepting an answer so that you don't discourage further answers which might provide other options.

Comment: Thanks Mark, I was actually uncertain about how long to wait before accepting the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are correct that kd-trees typically only work in small, Euclidean metric spaces. But, there is lots of work for general nearest neighbor applications in metric spaces (anywhere you can define a distance function essentially).

The classic work is on [ball trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ball_tree), which then were generalized to [metric trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_tree).

There is some newer work called [cover trees](http://hunch.net/~jl/projects/cover_tree/cover_tree.html) which even has GPL'ed code. I have wanted to look into the performance characteristics between these trees and kd-trees for more than two years now.

Hopefully, that fits your application.

Comment: Sorry to unaccept; just following another commenter's advice to give this question a few more days to "stew". I really found your answer helpful, though!

Comment: Booo. Just kidding. I am just happy that you found this helpful.

Answer (score 0):

A simple option for approximate neighbor search in non-euclidean spaces is using $sqrt(N)$ samples in the search. This has been implemented in OMPL, see [`ompl::NearestNeighborsSqrtApprox< _T >` Class Template Reference](http://ompl.kavrakilab.org/classompl_1_1NearestNeighborsSqrtApprox.html).

This reduces complexity to $O(sqrt(N))$.